# Dynamic lync and JSON array

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

I'm writing a .NET Core app and I need to build a string to be used with Dynamic Linq.

The following condition is working if used with a normal linq condition but I have no idea how to translate it in a string to be used in Dynamic Linq.

```
x => x.JSONCustomPropertiesValues != null && JArray.Parse(x.JSONCustomPropertiesValues).Any(y => (int)y["CustomProperty_Id"] == 27 && y["IntValue"] != null && y["IntValue"].Value<int?>() == 48)
```

I have tried to write it in this way

```
s = "x => x.JSONCustomPropertiesValues != null && JArray.Parse(x.JSONCustomPropertiesValues).Any(y => (int)y[\"CustomProperty_Id\"] == 27 && y[\"IntValue\"] != null && y[\"IntValue\"].Value<int?>() == 48)";
```

but using it in this way gives error:

```
query = query.Where(s, parms);
```

Do you have some idea on how to solve this problem?

Thank you

**UPDATE 1**

Here a little more details of my class

```
public static System.Linq.IQueryable<T> Where<T>(
    this System.Linq.IQueryable<T> query,
    string parm1,
    string parm2
    ) where T : class
{

// omissis
// This below is the line to change
q = "(DynamicQueryable.ParseJToken(x.JSONCustomPropertiesValues).Any(y => (int)y[\"CustomProperty_Id\"] == 27 && y[\"IntValue\"] != null && DynamicQueryable.GetValue<int?>(y[\"IntValue\"]) == 48))";
query = query.Where(q, values.ToArray());

}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Looking to the answer of Chintan Dhokai maybe I was not so clear.
I have a database with a table defined as

```
public class MyTable {
// ... different fields
public string JSONCustomPropertiesValues
}
```

Fhe field JSONCustomPropertiesValues represents a JSON array and the string could be something like

```
[
  {
    "CustomProperty_Id": 27,
    "IntValue": 48
  },
  {
    "CustomProperty_Id": 28,
    "IntValue": 50
  }
]
```

The result that I want is to get all records of MyTable where JSONCustomPropertiesValues has an entry with CustomProperty_Id=27 and IntValue=48. So the result is the whole MyTable record, not the item inside JSONCustomPropertiesValues .

Comment: Are you sure that syntax is valid for the Dynamic Linq?

Comment: @Eldar No... the problem is that syntax is not valid for dynamic linq but I didn't find info about the translation of my linq syntax to dynamic linq